# Determining the Asymptotic Order of Growth of the Generalized Harmonic Function?

Tags: asymptotics, harmonic-functions

How should I proceed to determine the order of growth of the generalized harmonic numbers?

$$
H_{n}^{(r)} \in \mathcal{O}(?)
$$

Comment: Are you referring to the [generalized harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalized_harmonic_numbers)?  Try comparing the sum to an integral.

Comment: Is $r$ the exponent? When $r > 1$ this is $o(1)$. What regime are you interested in?

Comment: Specifically, when $r = -\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Beware: the notation $H^{(r)}_n$ in the question is that used in wikipedia for [Hyperharmonic Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Hyperharmonic_numbers). Wikipedia uses $H_{n,r}$ for harmonic numbers, and I've seen $H_n^r$ also (where $r$ is the exponent: $H_{n,r}:=\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-r}$

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. For the notation, I relied much more on WolframAlpha, like [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=HarmonicNumber[n%2C+-1%2F2]).