# Evaluating a Limit with Generalized Harmonic Numbers.

Tags: limits, asymptotics, harmonic-functions

Using WolframAlpha, I could informally come up with the following result:

$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{H_n^{(-\frac{1}{2})}}{n\sqrt{n}} = \frac{2}{3}
$$

Allowing me to infer that $H_n^{(-\frac{1}{2})} \in \Theta(n\sqrt{n})$.

How to demonstrate/elaborate this limit ?

Comment: I wasn't joking with my comment on your [last question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/776335/5531).  Try to formalize the statement $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \sqrt{k} \approx \int_0^n \sqrt{x}\,dx.$$  [This page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) might give you some ideas.

Comment: Thank you @AntonioVargas, but I am not a pure mathematician, my bad. Therefore, using a formal speech without any notation sounds daunting to me. I'll try to figure out your suggestion.

Comment: Indeed, I applied your suggested solution, and I have now a solution with $\Theta$ notation!